# VisualSVN repositories on a NAS with Samba service

Tags: samba, visualsvn-server

I installed VisualSVN Server on my PC with Win8.1 and I'm trying to create repositories on a network share on my rather primitive NAS that runs a Samba service.
I created the user "svn" in Windows and in Samba with the same password and set VisualSVN Server service to log on as that user.
When I log in to Windows with that user (svn) I can access the share \\mynas\svn and create/modify/delete files there.
However, I get Access denied when I try to create a repository in that share via VisualSVN Server Manager.

Everything runs fine when I create a repository on a local disk. The service appears to be able to access the share \\mynas\svn. I saw an error on the service start when it logged on as "Network Service" because it could not access the storage root but id does not appear anymore since I've swiched the service to log on as "svn".
I start VisualSVN Server Manager in my "normal" Windows account that belongs to Administrators and has access to the share \\mynas\svn as well.

What else I could do to grant VisualSVN Server Manager access to that share?